# Adding more information to a string

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a gtf file like this:

```
ChrI    Coding_transcript       gene    8451772 8509212 .       -       .       gene_id "UMM-S589-0.12-gene-1"

ChrI    Coding_transcript       exon    8501974 8509212 .       -       .       gene_id "UMM-S589-0.12-gene-1"

ChrI    Coding_transcript       exon    8491643 8501928 .       -       0        gene_id "UMM-S589-0.12-gene-1"
```

I now want to add more information into column 9, to make it look like this:

```
ChrI    Coding_transcript       exon    8501974 8509212 .       -       .       gene_id "UMM-S589-0.12-gene-1"; transcript_id "UMM-S589-0.12-gene-1", exon_id "1";

ChrI    Coding_transcript       exon    8491643 8501928 .       -       0        gene_id "UMM-S589-0.12-gene-1";transcript_id "UMM-S589-0.12-gene-1", exon_id "2";
```

Does anyone know any simple command I can use to make this file? Thank you so much!

Comment: how do we get information about 9th column.. is that static, or plz explain if we have any condition.

Comment: hi SivaPrasath: thank you for your comment. I don't have any information, as you can see, I want to add the info based on what is present, i.e. gene_id and transcript_id are the same, and exon number is based on the number count of "exon" on 3rd column

Comment: I see 10 columns, with the 9th that just says "gene_id", but your example seems to append data after column 10.  Also it look like you're trying to count exon, and you're only appending to exon lines.  What you want is probably doable, but it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'NF==10{print $0";transcript_id "$10", exon_id ""\""++count[$3]"\""";"}NF!=10{print $0}' file.gtf
```

Output:

```
ChrI    Coding_transcript       exon    8501974 8509212 .       -       .       gene_id "UMM-S589-0.12-gene-1";transcript_id "UMM-S589-0.12-gene-1", exon_id "1";

ChrI    Coding_transcript       exon    8491643 8501928 .       -       0        gene_id "UMM-S589-0.12-gene-1";transcript_id "UMM-S589-0.12-gene-1", exon_id "2";
```

- `NF==10` check if the number of fields is 10.

  - `print $0` print the complete line.
  - `transcript_id $10` since it is same as gene_id
  - `++count[$3]` print the occerance of exon(3rd field)
- `NF!=10` just print the line.